# url encoding javascript of $0 value

Tags: javascript, regex, urlencode, url-encoding

I want to encode the value being pass by $0 in jsp, how can I do that?

Below is the snippet of the code:

```
..href='"url+"$0'>$0"
```

Comment: Are you talking about on the server or client? If it's the server, a JSP tag on the question might be appropriate.

Comment: @RobG what do you mean by server or client? Thank you.

Comment: The code looks like it should be run on the server. If you are trying to run that exact markup as HTML in a browser, it is invalid.

Comment: @RobG $0 was actually a value of a regex pName= pName.replaceFirst("((?<=^\\$[ \t\n\f\r]?)|(?<=[^\\x7F-\\xFF]\\$[ \t\n\f\r]?))[^ \t\n\f\r \\$]{1,}(?=[ \t\n\f\r]*)","<a href='"+url+"$0'>$0</a>");

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
url+encodeURIComponent($0)
```

Comment: Okay, I was under the impression $0 was a javascript variable. If you want to encode the whole `$0'>$0` just put it in quotes where I had `$0` before, like: `url+encodeURIComponent($0'>$0)`

Comment: I think $0 was a variable, but the syntax url+encodeURIComponent($0) does not work.. If I put quote on $0'>$0 it will treat it as a string..